# Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name captcha.(captchacheck)

Tags: codeigniter

I ve used the solution found here http://www.mahbubblog.com/php/form-validation-callbacks-in-hmvc-in-codeigniter/comment-page-2/#comment-5996. and its working on my CI 3.0 on Mac, however when i tried deploying the site to my Ubuntu server it produces the "Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name captcha.(captchacheck)".
Please help...

Thanks

```
function index(){
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', 'Company', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'captcha', 'trim|strip_tags|callback_captcha_check|match_captcha[captcha.word]');
  $data = $this->get_data_from_post();
    if ($this->form_validation->run($this) === false){
       $data['image'] = $this->captcha_model->create_image();
       $data['view_file'] = 'registration';
       $data['js']="";
       $data['module'] = 'users';
       $this->load->module('template');
       $this->template->site($data); 
    }
    else{
       $data2 = $this->get_data_from_post();
       $this->db->insert('ict_users',$data2);
       $data['view_file'] = 'success';
       $data['js']="";
       $data['module'] = 'users';
       $this->load->module('template');
       $this->template->site($data); 
    } 
}

function captcha_check($value){
    if($value==''){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('captcha_check','Please enter the text from the image');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please remove 
match_captcha[captcha.word]
You need to use a callback for it below given

public function validate_captcha(){
    if($this->input->post('captcha') != $this->session->userdata['captcha'])
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_captcha', 'Wrong captcha code, hmm are you the Terminator?');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: @user1372324I forgot to mention that i have extended form validation and i included the match_captcha function inside that class:

Comment: den try putting                                                                                              $this->form_validation->set_message('captcha_check','Please enter the text from the image'); below                        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'captcha', 'trim|strip_tags|callback_captcha_check|match_captcha[captcha.word]');